# Emit a class at runtime in AS3 with fast memory opcodes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory

There are a couple of libraries listed below, that allow you to dynamically generate an ActionScript class by emitting the ABC (Actionscript Byte Code) tags necessary and loading the generated IL as an SWF into Flash Player.

Which of these libraries is small and fast library, and supports generation of a class with methods/vars, and supports the latest "fast memory" opcodes? Yes, I'm already doing my own research but just asking if someone already has experience with this.

- [As3-commons-bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/index.html) - Currently the most active project
- [Loom](https://code.google.com/p/loom-as3/) - Oldest project, now closed by author - Continues as as3-commons
- [FLEmit](https://code.google.com/p/flemit/) - ??
- [Floxy](https://code.google.com/p/floxy/) - ??
- [AsMock](http://asmock.sourceforge.net/) - ??